# React Native: Style Dependent on State is updating, but not rendering accordingly

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

**Some Background:**

Currently I'm trying to implement a TouchableOpacity component that represents a switch, which has a state of either 'on' or 'off'. The component works as follows:

- On load, the component reads using AsyncStorage using the current date as the key (if an entry exists for the key, then the component has the state 'on' (true), if not 'off' (false)
- The background color of the child View component is related to the state ('on': backgroundColor is green; 'off': backgroundColor is 'none')
- If the component is pressed, the component is disabled while waiting for the AsyncStorage method to complete.
- If the component is pressed while the state is 'off', a new entry is written, and on completion, the state is set to 'on'.
- If the component is pressed while the state is 'on', the entry with the given key is deleted, and the state is set to 'off'.

**Current Code:**

```
class Switch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                    switchStatus: null,
                    awaitingIO: false
            };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
            switchStatusOfDate(new Date()).then((response) => {
                    this.setState({ switchStatus: response != null ? true : false });
            }).catch((error) => {
                    // error
            });
    }

    render() {
            const {switchStatus, awaitingIO } = this.state;
            if (switchStatus == null) {
                    return <View style={[styles.circleButton]}>
                            <Text>Loading</Text>
                    </View>
            }

            const style = {
                    backgroundColor: switchStatus ? 'green' : 'none',
                    ...styles.circleButton
            };

            return (<TouchableOpacity disabled={awaitingIO} onPress={this._updateSwitchStatus.bind(this)} >
                    <View style={style}>
                            {/* Some children */}
                    </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>);
    }

    async _updateSwitchStatus() {
            this.setState({ awaitingIO: true });

            if (this.state.switchStatus) {
                    await unsetSwitchStatusForDate(new Date());
            } else {
                    await setSwitchStatusForDate(new Date());
            }

            this.setState({
                    switchStatus: !this.state.switchStatus,
                    awaitingIO: false,
            });
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        circleButton: {
                flex: 0,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 75,
                borderColor: 'green'
        },
});

export default Switch;
```

**Storage Methods:**

```
function getDateKey(date) {
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let month = date.getMonth();
        let day = date.getDate();

        return `@${year}${month}${day}`;
}

export async function switchStatusOfDate(date) {
        try {
                return await AsyncStorage.getItem(getDateKey(date));
        } catch (e) {
                // error
        }
}

export async function setSwitchStatusForDate(date) {
        try {
                let value = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
                return await AsyncStorage.setItem(getDateKey(date), value);
        } catch (e) {
                // error
        }
}

export async function unsetSwitchStatusForDate(date) {
        try {
                await AsyncStorage.removeItem(getDateKey(date));
        } catch (e) {
                // error
        }
}
```

**The Problem:**
Currently, on load, the background color is set correctly (if the component is pressed to set the state to 'on', and an entry is written, upon reloading the application, the component background color is green). Also, when the state is loaded as 'off' (no entry exists), and I press the component, the background color changes from 'none' to green correctly. However, all further presses have no impact on the background color.

The state is being set correctly, and the AsyncStorage methods are also working. I've tried logging the switchStatus and style in the render() method, and the values returned are correct, but it doesn't have any effect on the actual render (it stays green no matter).

Does anyone know why this might be?

I feel like there's an obvious solution to this that I'm just missing, so any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1:** I did alter some variable names so the code is self-contained to the question, but nothing else was changed (just in case there's any errors that are spotted caused by it).

**Edit/Update 2:** I've noticed that when using the element inspector with expo on my phone, the css property backgroundColor: 'none' is applied to the view, but it's background in the render is still green. This isn't due to any children components either, as I've removed them and it's still the case.

Comment: First of all you should use the second form of setState
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using,

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
```

or

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

where the last value in the first one is the opacity (in this case, completely transparent), works.

My problem was that I thought 'none' was a valid value for backgroundColor in css. This was not the case, whoops!